# determining child element evaluated width for auto width parent

Tags: html, css

When an element has a width of auto, and it's child has a percentage width, how is the width of the child calculated? I have a fiddle here which demonstrates the confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/w2c3ex21/

Here it is in code:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        this is my contents
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.column {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I would possibly expect, the width of each column being 150px but instead it is 212px. Can somebody explain?

Comment: your attitude toward people trying to help you isn't very nice, sorry. please see my responses below. you're not doing yourself any favors. I'll let you figure this out yourself.

Comment: @Timmerz someone in the future may stumble upon this same problem and think you are correct, when in fact you are not and are spreading misinformation. guessing answers and trying to pass them off as facts is not helpful to the community and you should stop doing it.

Comment: how can you say I'm passing things off as facts if you also say I'm guessing? you say I am spreading misinformation when below you state "position absolute, absolutely does not change the display property of an element" when I just proved that it did. so it would be you spreading misinformation and stating things you don't know and passing it off as fact.

Answer (score -1):

The child width is calculated based off the parent width. In this case you chose `auto` for parent, so the browser determines the best fit. Normally this would be 100% in the case of `display:block` default for `div` or 100% of the parent of the element using `width:auto` from what I understand.

In this case you used `position:absolute` which changed the display to `inline-block` or `inline` essentially, so it fits to your content.

I'm not sure why you expected 150px?

Comment: I am agree with you @Timmerz

Comment: why do you post a reply when you're unsure of the answer? position absolute, absolutely does not change the display property of an element

Comment: without `position:absolute` is easy to explain, but that changes everything for it's children, "essentially, so it fits to your content." still not clear how it's calculated?

Comment: if you take off `position:absolute` you will see it expand to a `display:block` formatting. check for yourself. in this case you are wrong. @sahbeewah

Comment: I'm explaining what I do know. must everyone be silent unless they can explain every detail to perfection?

Comment: ok got it, i'm willing to hear more. i didn't voted it down, i actually voted it up back to "0" :P

Comment: @Timmerz "if you take off position:absolute you will see it expand to a display:block formatting." this is erroneous logic and is not helpful to the question. furthermore, despite all, it doesn't answer the question. it is clearly not wrapped around the text

Comment: @sahbeewah you need to back that up with facts explaining your case. I go to the fiddle. I click off `position:absolute` it expands to 100% width. this is the same as `display:block` now (default for `div`), explain why it is erroneous?

Comment: @sdcr I wasn't talking to you...was referring to sahbeewah. no worries.

Comment: @sahbeewah go to the fiddle. add `display:inline-block` to the parent. now turn off `position:absolute` you will see it is the same! now, turn off `display:inline-block` you will see it expand to `display:block`. so prove me wrong, or else you just proved yourself wrong.

Comment: ummm! @Timmerz i know you were talking to @sahbeewah, no worries too. l actually actually voted both of you up. sahbeewah you didn't mention any words about the `absolute` thing in your question, but it is there in your code. and Timmerz did his best to answer that one, so stop fighting, we go figure it out, will check back tomorrow. very late here now ET zone.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this css

```
.column img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2c3ex21/2/)